# Access not installed in PC, Application not running.?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012

I have copied my application in another PC and its not working there. I have database of Access. The application gets data from the access database using the code. My question is how can I make my application working when access is not installed?

THe file is present in the folder which address i have given in the connectionString. So the real problem is not the address.Its that access is not installed.

i am using following code to get data from database :

```
private DataTable GetDataFromDatabase(string queryString)
{
    var connectionString = string.Format(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\mat1546\NewFolder\Db6;Persist Security Info=False;");

    var adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(queryString, connectionString);
    var ds = new DataSet();

    adapter.Fill(ds, "Table");

    DataTable data = ds.Tables["Table"];
    return data;
}
    DataTable data2 = GetDataFromDatabase("select * from Table ");
                    DataRow prevRow2 = null;
                    bool flag = false;
                    bool flag2 = false;
                    foreach (DataRow row in data.Rows)
                    {
                        double wheelAlpha, trackAlpha;
                        int dbSpan;

                        if (double.TryParse(row["Price"].ToString(), out price2) && double.TryParse(row["Amount"].ToString(), out amount2))
                        {
                            int.TryParse(row["Quantity"].ToString(), out quantitiy2);

                            if (Quantity == quantity2 && Market_price < price2 && flag == false)
                            {
                                totalamountTb.Text = prevRow2["Market_price"].ToString();
                                flag = true;
                            }
                         }


                        prevRow2 = row;
                    }
```

Comment: Do you have the database in this folder on the other PC? `C:\BridgeClassificationApp\BridgeClassificationApp\bin\Debug\Database5.accdb`

Comment: Yes Steve, I have the Database on the other pc is well. Actually there is no access installed in that PC. Its creating problem.

Comment: How do you expect to get to the Data that should be in the Access DB if you have no Access DB?

Comment: You don't need to have Access (The Microsoft program part of Office suite) installed. However you need to have the free distributable [Access Database Engine](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255) for the correct bitness of the target operating system installed

Comment: As a side note, try to understand how to put a connectionstring in a config file, so you could move your database in whichever folder is available on your target machine

Comment: Click properties on your provider reference (Microsoft ace) in visual studio and change the "CopyLocale" to true..this will add Ace dll to you project's executable directory..And then you won't need to have check Ace on target computer.. And As Steve noted try to find generic way to Database connection something like AppPath\Your Folder

Comment: thank u sir for the help. i will try it now. if not, then i will leave comment

Comment: And you need to have an Access CAL for every user.

Comment: how will i do that. i am newbie if u can explain. plz

Comment: Or just don't use Access.... If you really need an "In a file" solution, use Compact Framework. Even better, SQL express. SQLLite works too (also "In a file") Access is the bottom rung of RDBMSs